# what regex expression in python for this text

Tags: python, regex

I have a complicated text file, here is part of it:

```
& \multirow{2}{*}{52.7} & \multirow{2}{*}{3} & \multirow{2}{*}{$<$ 0.001}\\
```

I'm interested in the numbers after the `{*}`. Here is what I tried with no luck:

```
import re
m = re.findall(r'{\*}{(.+)}', '& \multirow{2}{*}{52.7} & \multirow{2}{*}{3} & \multirow{2}{*} $<$ 0.001}\\')
```

However, I get the following result:

```
['52.7} & \\multirow{2}{*}{3} & \\multirow{2}{*}{$<$ 0.001']
```

I tried many other combinations but I either get the first number (e.g 52.7), or the middle number (3) or the above. How can I get `52.7, 3, $<$ 0.001` in a group (list).

Comment: Your first regex obviously won't work (quantifiers are greedy), however I am curious as to what you expect your regex to match in your third example, ie `\multirow{2}{*}{$<$ 0.001}`?

Comment: I wanted the bit between the last set of curly brackets; `$<$ 0.001`. It's working now after adding the `?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because by default `+` and `*` operators are greedy. Use non-greedy modification instead:

```
{\*}{(.+?)}
```

Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html ("*Watch Out for The Greediness!*" section)

Answer (score 1):

use the following regex expression:

```
\{\*\}\{(.*?)\}
```

you should escape all special characters with backslash `\` and use non-greedy wildcard `.*?` in a subclass for result set.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = re.findall(r'({\*}{([\d|\.?]+?)})+', '& \multirow{2}{*}{52.7} & \multirow{2}{*}{3} & \multirow{2}{*} $<$ 0.001}\\')
[('{*}{52.7}', '52.7'), ('{*}{3}', '3')]

m = re.findall(r'{\*}{([\d|\.?]+?)}+', '& \multirow{2}{*}{52.7} & \multirow{2}{*}{3} & \multirow{2}{*} $<$ 0.001}\\')
['52.7', '3']

m = re.findall(r'{\*}{(.*?)}', '& \multirow{2}{*}{52.7} & \multirow{2}{*}{3} & \multirow{2}{*} $<$ 0.001}\\')
['52.7', '3', '$<$ 0.001']
```